# How effective is golf equipment against zombies?

Tags: warfare, zombies

A golf club is being besieged by zombies. What standard golfing (and golf-course) equipment would make the most effective weapons to repel them?

Comment: You may want to define the rules of your zombies, that will make  answers a lot more concrete. but look up a piece of groundskeeping equipment called a brush hook, https://www.grainger.com/product/12N147?gclid=EAIaIQobChMInM2C8bX_4QIV1IWzCh0sXQ24EAQYAiABEgKc3vD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMInM2C8bX_4QIV1IWzCh0sXQ24EAQYAiABEgKc3vD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916771597!!!s!137382016642!

Comment: @John - that is a *very shiny* blade and I rather want one.  Have no use for it, but it is neat.

Answer (score 5):

The single best thing on the golf course for dealing with zombies is the clubhouse. Usually arranged over several stories with a bar on at least one level, what you should do is go upstairs and demolish the stairs behind you. The groundskeeper or caretaker will have suitable tools for this stashed somewhere around the place.

While it could be difficult to fully barricade a building, not having any way to make it to the upper levels will be an effective deterrent to even the most determined zombie.

Answer (score 4):

Is it wrong to state the obvious here? The best weapons will be the golf clubs; in particular, the irons 8-2. Personally, I would go with a 7 iron. It will have the best weight to length ratio for exploding heads. Also, it will still have enough loft if I want to make a few trick shot kills with a golf ball. Now, if I can make it to the ground's keeping hut, I will want to do that because there will most likely be a chainsaw there and a pretty large supply of fuel (for chainsaw and bombs).

Answer (score 3):

The ball gathering vehicle for the driving range is already well armored with a fully enclosed, steel-reinforced cage around the driver's compartment.  When you get down to your last survivor, she can ride off into the sunset in that already-zombie-ready little vehicle.

Also, there are equipment opportunities hidden in the club's high style decor.  For example, it would be totally believable for the club's fine dining room to be decorated in medieval style.  The ornamentation might include swords, axes and maybe even a suit of armor.  The kitchen which serves that dining room will also be full of large knives, rolling pins and pot-top shields.

Finally, there is a golf tournament style called a "ShotGun" where the golfers begin their rounds simultaneously with a couple foursomes on the tee of each hole.  This greatly increases the course utilization and allows everyone to start and finish at the same time, as opposed to each foursome starting on the first tee sequentially.  Play begins when everyone hears a shotgun which the groundskeeper fires off near the clubhouse.  FIND THAT SHOTGUN!!!!!